# Question On Sequential Attacks / Finishing Sequence Early

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a top down game where when you press the attack button multiple times there's a 3 hit sequence. I have the 3 hit sequence working just fine, but I have two problems I can't seem to find a solution to through my google fu.

When the sequence is finished, I don't have a good way to transition back to the idle state.

When you press the button once or twice, I'm not sure how I can tell whether you haven't pressed the button again in a long enough time to decide the sequence has been cancelled.

(I'm using a state machine I made for the character controller, and the states don't inherit from monobehavior so I don't have access to coroutines in this attack state)

Here is the code, I would really appreciate some feedback and help.

```cs
private string currentAttack = "Attack1";

public AttackingState(Character character, StateMachine stateMachine) 
  : base(character, stateMachine)
{
}

public override void Action()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        switch (currentAttack)
        {
            case "Attack1":
            {
                this.character.SetTrigger("Attack2");
                this.currentAttack = "Attack2";
                break;
            }
            case "Attack2":
            {
                this.character.SetTrigger("Attack3");
                this.currentAttack = "Attack3";
                break;
            }
            case "Attack3":
            {
                this.character.SetTrigger("Attack1");
                this.currentAttack = "Attack1";
                break;
            }
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") != 0 || Input.GetAxis("Vertical") != 0)
    {
        character.SetTrigger("AttackCancelled");
        stateMachine.SetState<WalkingState>(new WalkingState(character, stateMachine));
        currentAttack = "Attack1";
    }
}

public override void OnStateEnter()
{
    base.OnStateEnter();
    character.SetTrigger("Attack1");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could track a timestamp since the last press and do something like

```
// stores the last attack time
private float lastAttackTime;
// whereever you want to assign this value from
// The delay before the attack is reset and starts over from 1
private const float MAX_ATTACK_INTERVAL = 1f;

if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
{
    // Time.time is the time in seconds since the app was started
    if(Time.time - lastAttackTime > MAX_ATTACK_INTERVAL)
    {
        // start over
        // mimics the attack3 since there you start over at 1
        currentAttack = "Attack3";
    }
    lastAttackTime = Time.time;

    switch (currentAttack)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

In general instead of `string` I would recommend either a simple `int` or an `enum` instead.

Comment: Hmm ok, how can I make sure this lines up with the end of the attack animation so the character doesn't sit there frozen in a pose?

Comment: oh then I would go another approach: Simply set it up in your Animator so that e.g. Attack1 -> Attack2 (via trigger) or Attack1 -> idle state after certain time. So purely set up in the Animator.

Comment: Awesome, that works. Do you know of how I can prevent the user from cancellation the attacks/animations by rapidly pressing the attack button? I want the attacks to be chained, but right now it cancels if the user rapidly presses space.